# Rotating and moving 2D-objects on mouse drag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, move

I wanted to recreate a game (tangram) where you can rotate and move the pieces.
The game can be found on this website: https://de.mathigon.org/tangram

I have found scripts for rotating and moving the object (a png-file) but when I add the two scripts togehter the object moves randomly around. As programme I use Unity.

The script for moving:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DragDropScript : MonoBehaviour {
private Vector3 screenPoint;
     private Vector3 offset;
 
 
     void OnMouseDown()
     {
         Debug.Log("mouse down");
         screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
         offset = transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
     }
 
     void OnMouseDrag()
     {
         Debug.Log("mouse drag");
         Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
         Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
         transform.position = curPosition;
    
    }
}
```

And the script for rotating

```
using UnityEngine;
     using System.Collections;
     
     public class ObjectRotator : MonoBehaviour 
     {
         
         private float _sensitivity;
         private Vector3 _mouseReference;
         private Vector3 _mouseOffset;
         private Vector3 _rotation;
         private bool _isRotating;
         
         void Start ()
         {
             _sensitivity = 0.4f;
             _rotation = Vector3.zero;
         }
         
         void Update()
         {
             if(_isRotating)
             {
                 // offset
                 _mouseOffset = (Input.mousePosition - _mouseReference);
                 
                 // apply rotation
                 _rotation.z = -(_mouseOffset.x + _mouseOffset.y) * _sensitivity;
                 
                 // rotate
                 transform.Rotate(_rotation);
                 
                 // store mouse
                 _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
             }
         }
         
         void OnMouseDown()
         {
             // rotating flag
             _isRotating = true;
             
             // store mouse
             _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
         }
         
         void OnMouseUp()
         {
             // rotating flag
             _isRotating = false;
         }
         
     }
```

So far I struggle with Unity. In my bachelor-thesis I got a HoloLens2 and could use the MRTK which really helped developing a application. Thank you in advanced.
At the end the game should be built as WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

The random result is probably due to trying to move and rotate the object at the same time. An easy fix for this would be to move on left mouse button and rotate with right click, or vice versa. You can use [Input.GetMouseButton](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html) to check if a button is pressed and insert checks in the script to only move *OR* rotate.

More complicated solutions would involve some kind of "widget" that is dragged, that way you can have different widgets for drag and rotate.

I would also recommend learning a bit of geometry and trigonometry to be able to understand the posted scripts. Copying scripts of the internet will only get you so far.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to make this application work on a touch device? Unitys documentation about Input.GetTouch does not provide enough information because on touch devices you cannot choose left or right mouse pressed. I also tried to use the method with the "widget". Therefore I created a circle with a line connecting o the object. But somehow I struggle with moving and rotating the object because I cannot find the right hierarchie-order of the object.

Comment: @LeeDatAR I'm not sufficiently familiar with unity to provide any specific recommendations.